# What is happening with this code?

Tags: c++, templates, android-ndk

I'm trying to develop an Android keyboard using the Android AOSP Keyboard source as a model. There's quite a bit of JNI code, my C++ is a bit rusty, and I'm having trouble with the following definition for a macro `NELEMS`:

```
// Disclaimer: You will see a compile error if you use this macro against a variable-length array.
// Sorry for the inconvenience. It isn't supported.
template <typename T, int N>
char (&ArraySizeHelper(T (&array)[N]))[N];
#define NELEMS(x) (sizeof(ArraySizeHelper(x)))
```

When I try to compile, the second line of this code (just above the `#define`) lights up with an error:

> Declaration of reference variable requires an initializer

The error message makes some sense to me; the AOSP code does not. The symbol `ArraySizeHelper` occurs nowhere else in the AOSP code or make files (that is, as far as I can tell it's not a macro for something else).

From the name of the macro, I would guess that it is supposed to evaluate to the number of elements in the array. As far as I know, though, the usual way to do that would be:

```
#define NELEMS(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))
```

so I'm wondering if something else is going on here.

I'd appreciate an explanation of what this code is supposed to do and guidance on what to do about the compile error.

**EDIT:** I'm compiling through Android Studio 1.3 RC 3, Android NDK r10e, and Gradle 2.5. Compilation uses various toolchains (as described in [this Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html)). Strangely, the above code now compiles and executes correctly (perhaps it always did). However, Android studio still displays an error on that line. It also displays an error on every use of `NELEMS`:

> Error after macro substitution: Too many arguments, expected 0

I'm now thinking that this is an IDE code analysis error, not a compiler or coding problem. My original question was about the code itself, so I'm marking this thread as answered. I'll open another question about what seems to be an IDE problem. Thanks to everyone for the explanations!

Comment: Take that second way you're trying and consider how it *works* (but not how you would want) if you provide a *pointer* for the argument, and how the first addresses that issue. As far as the first is concerned, you may wish to provide the C++ compiler toolchain info you're using, as it works with nearly every C++ compiler I've used for the last decade ([see it live](http://ideone.com/l3OWYN)). The thing that usually throws people with the first is that the actual template function need never be *implemented*, yet it still works.

Comment: How exactly are you compiling it? (Older compilers may have trouble with the syntax.)

Comment: @AlanStokes - I'm using the standard toolchains provided by the Android NDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
template <typename T, int N>
char (&ArraySizeHelper(T (&array)[N]))[N];
```

declares a function named `ArraySizeHelper` that takes a reference to an array of `N` `T`s named `array` and returns a reference to an array of `char[N]`. There is no definition given.

`sizeof()` does not require a definition of a function - it's operand is unevaluated. It just operates on the type: so `sizeof(ArrayHelper(x))` evalutes to `sizeof(char[N])` if the type of `x` is `T[N]` (and doesn't compile otherwise).

It's also a horribly complex way of just writing:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t array_size(T (&)[N]) { return N; }
```

which is far far easier to understand. And doesn't require a macro.

Comment: I concur with the assessment of doing this with `constexpr` today. Alas nearly all the usages of the OP's post (I first saw it in MS ATL 3.1) came *long* before that was a language feature. (ex: your simplification will not compile on VS2008; the OP's first snippet *will*).

Comment: The `constexpr` code looks fine but is useless, because the standard forbids you passing an actual argument (lvalue). Silly. Yes!

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf that plain sucks, because I really like that simplification.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf `template <size_t> struct TD; constexpr int x[42]{}; TD<array_size(x)> t;` compiles on gcc and clang.

Comment: @Barry: I had to research a bit, but I've now updated my answer with the relevant quote from C++14 (N3936 final draft, §5.19/2 9th dash). I'm unable to reproduce with Visual C++ and g++, but maybe clang is problematic. But the reason I remembered it is I once posted formally invalid code here on SO, exactly the code you posted except no needless `size_t` ;-), and someone pointed it out to me.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf What needeless `size_t`? Also, the quote you posted is about references - in my comment (and the code in your answer) `x` isn't a reference, it's an array.

Comment: @Barry: Yes it's about references. That's why the compiles-fine-with-gcc-and-clang code you showed, is completely irrelevant. That code is a demonstration that *something else* is OK. It goes not to the problem. Code to check whether compilers are impractically strict has to call `array_size` with an argument that is a reference.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation of what that declaration does. It makes perfect sense and I'm only left wondering (see my question edit) why the Android Studio editor chokes on it.

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of the code is to safely get an array size that can be used at compile time, e.g. as the size of new raw (non-dynamic) array.

The simple definition

```
#define NELEMS(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))
```

… is unsafe because you can pass a pointer to it, and get back a nonsense size.

So the code you have,

```
template <typename T, int N>
char (&ArraySizeHelper(T (&array)[N]))[N];
#define NELEMS(x) (sizeof(ArraySizeHelper(x)))
```

… uses template argument deduction to *find* the size, and it uses a reference-to-array return type to report the size as a compile time constant. If not for a <sup>(1)</sup>silly wording in C++11 and onwards about passing references, we could now do the same with `constexpr`. Alas, we'll probably have to wait until C++17 before macros can be completely avoided for the simple task of obtaining a compile time array size.

---

I'm unable to reproduce the problem; the following code:

```
template <typename T, int N>
char (&ArraySizeHelper(T (&array)[N]))[N];
#define NELEMS(x) (sizeof(ArraySizeHelper(x)))

#include <iostream>
auto main() -> int
{
    using namespace std;
    int x[42];
    cout << NELEMS( x ) << endl;
}
```

compiles nicely with both Visual C++ 2015 and MinGW-64 g++ 5.1.0.

---

<sup><sup>1)</sup> C++14 §5.19/2 “A *conditional-expression* `e` is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the
abstract machine (1.9), would evaluate one of the following expressions: […] — an *id-expression* that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and either
— it is initialized with a constant expression or
— it is a non-static data member of an object whose lifetime began within the evaluation of `e`;”</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I suspected that it might have something to do with type safety, but my C++ was too rusty to figure out what was happening.